# Service Bus Queue doesn't remove completed messages

Tags: azure, servicebus

I'm sending an HTTP Post message to a Service Bus Queue and when this receive it, a Logic App starts. But when the Logic App finishes sometimes the message is n ot removed from the queue and this restart the Logic App.

What can I do for remove this messages?

Comment: Interesting question. I thought the whole point was, when a service reads a message from SMBQ the message is consumed.

Answer (score 1):

This may help. When you make a logic app resource a single instance, it is recommended to use a Peek/Lock trigger.   Otherwise the message doesn't leave the queue until the next trigger runs.

Ref:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e2eb4505-cb7e-4bad-aeaf-1da2e10739d4/whenamessageisreceivedinaqueueautocomplete-trigger-is-not-deleting-the-message-off-the?forum=azurelogicapps

Comment: Yes, Peek and Confirm Removal is different.  If you don't intentionally call .Complete or .Abandon, the message will "time out" and resurrect back onto the queue.  here is complete helper url : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.complete?view=azure-dotnet      .Abandon is very close by.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that was no errors in Logic App. Error would rollback transaction (if message consumption is part of transaction) and leave message on queue for next attempt.